# How automatically generate variables and calculate it from different data frames?

Tags: r

I'm currently have three data frames A, B, C and devoting to calculating P and H values for each individual. A dataframe is the weights of each indicators. In B dataframe, each row means different person and all values in each row means different indicators of each person. And each person has 8 p values. When I calculate P1-P8 values, it is kinda of tricky process because I need to retrieve values of each column in A, values of each row in B.

For example, for first individual, they have eight P values. Firstly, P1 = a11 (1st value of a1 column) * d11 (1st value of 1st row) + a12 (2nd value of a1 column) * d2i1 (2st value of 1st row) + .... + a18 (8th value of a1 column) * d4iii1 (8th value of 1st row)

Similarly, P**n** (**n**=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 i.e. the number of P) equal a**n**1 (1st value of a**n** column) * d1 (1th value of 1st row) + a**n**2 * d2i**n** + ... + a**n**8 (8th value of a**n** column)* d4iii**n** (8th value of 1th row).

As long as we get the P value, for this person, H = (c1 * p1 + c2 * p2 + ... + c8 * p8) / (the sum of c values)

This is the process of calculating P and H values for first person. If I want to get these for other person, I need to switch to another row in B dataframe. For second person, P1 = a11 (1st value of a1 column) * d11 (1st value of 2nd row) +
a12 (2nd value of a1 column) * d2i1 (2st value of 2nd row) + .... + a18 (8th value of a1 column) * d4iii1 (8th value of 2nd row)

and so on.....

I wonder how to automatically generate Pn variables for each person (because I have many persons in my dataset and they all have 8 P values for themselves) and store them in a new dataframe with their id (i.e. in dataframe B which row they belong to). And how to get H values for each person and store them in a new dataframe with their id. Do I need to use for loop?

Thanks in advance. This question has already bothered me for long time.

This below is dataframe A

```
           a1         a2          a3          a4          a5          a6
[1,] 0.3692138  0.1996207  0.33206893 -0.56119398 -0.08408712  0.26602100
[2,] 0.3145976  0.1092697 -0.73795950 -0.05969218 -0.30413354  0.03878391
[3,] 0.2460529 -0.5651003 -0.39410544 -0.32388500  0.40546811  0.14228006
[4,] 0.3222877  0.4139147 -0.17635789  0.59190345  0.32542055  0.14541092
[5,] 0.3411728  0.4788865  0.05223981 -0.32157631  0.36949738 -0.40617999
[6,] 0.4343109 -0.0797815  0.08669171  0.09679937 -0.67808516 -0.19700746
[7,] 0.4087344 -0.1867772  0.31806058  0.23704899  0.07403367  0.58710855
[8,] 0.3580635 -0.4323943  0.21752657  0.23931841  0.16828680 -0.58124876
             a7         a8
[1,] -0.5049092  0.2566187
[2,] -0.2824577 -0.4088489
[3,]  0.2393132  0.3434825
[4,] -0.1243642  0.4481563
[5,]  0.4220109 -0.2617724
[6,]  0.4172609  0.3397135
[7,]  0.2169848 -0.4933922
[8,] -0.4396189 -0.1442195
```

This below is dataframe B

```
              d1        d2i        d2ii        d3i         d3ii
 [1,]  2.2274980  0.2326252 -0.36403204  1.0739447  1.755403659
 [2,] -0.3992994 -0.5938799 -0.43979975 -0.6239955  0.003876488
 [3,]  0.6507902  1.3874935 -0.00927353  1.4067272  1.585108666
 [4,] -0.8035235 -1.0849895 -1.02000495 -1.0752411 -1.040682924
 [5,] -1.0362378  0.1243315 -0.50852517  1.3145696 -0.481857193
 [6,] -0.6401465 -0.9604119 -0.38205492 -1.0742542 -0.873746856
 [7,] -0.3017772 -0.9956345 -0.48684163 -0.5369783 -0.451910416
 [8,] -0.1562037  1.5676411  0.95787726 -0.1114577 -0.249915890
 [9,]  0.4588999  0.3228244  2.25265473 -0.3733147 -0.246275535
              d4i       d4ii      d4iii
 [1,]  1.82026675  1.6995820  1.0502324
 [2,] -0.54785322 -0.7978294 -0.5473042
 [3,] -0.06861184 -0.2715582 -0.5473042
 [4,] -1.09490583 -1.1478482 -0.8135603
 [5,]  0.32763531  0.5250373  0.5177202
 [6,] -0.96009257 -0.8268047 -0.6804322
 [7,] -0.97214626 -0.3313835 -0.8135603
 [8,]  0.53548889 -0.2468898 -0.2144841
 [9,]  0.96021878  1.3976945  2.0486927
```

Dataframe C

```
[1,] 4.860280668
[2,] 1.526722855
[3,] 0.892681697
[4,] 0.546369771
[5,] 0.127146103
[6,] 0.036401438 
[7,] 0.010293019
[8,] 0.000104449
```

Comment: I might be mistaken but if I understand correctly you are simply trying to cacluate the matrix product. The corresponding operator in R is `%*%`.

Comment: @Roland Thanks for your reply! I tried A %*% B but R return an error message related to non-conformable arguments

Comment: I think you want `B %*% A`?

Comment: Sorry @Roland, it works well though,  the results are still not what I want. If I want to calculate P values for first person. Each value in a1 column need to multiple by the corresponding values of first row in data B. e.g. P1 = 0.3692138 * 2.2274980 + 0.3145976 * - 0.3992994 + 0.2460529 * 0.6507902 .... For P2, each value in a2 column need to multiple by the corresponding values of first row in data B.

Comment: Do you know how matrix multiplication works? Then you should be able to figure this out. If not, provide your input in a usable way (see `help("dput")`) and show the expected output.

Comment: Oops! Thanks @Roland. I think I misunderstood matrix multiplication function. Very thanks for your instruction and patience : )